# Setting image quality using UIGraphicsPDFRenderer

Tags: swift, uikit

Trying to add a Aztec barcode to a PDF using UIGraphicsPDFRenderer my issue is that the result is blurry thought the fix was setting interpolationQuality, Thanks for your help.

```
  let renderer = UIGraphicsPDFRenderer(bounds: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 70.8661, height: 70.8661))

    return renderer.pdfData{ ctx in
        
            ctx.beginPage()
            ctx.cgContext.interpolationQuality = .none //Doesn't do anything

            let barcode = generateQRCode(from: UUID().description)
            barcode.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 70.8661, height: 70.8661))

    }



   func generateQRCode(from string: String) -> UIImage {
       filter.message = Data(string.utf8)

       if let outputImage = filter.outputImage {
           if let cgimg = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent) {
                return  UIImage(cgImage: cgimg)
           }
       }

    return UIImage()
  }
```

Comment: I'm printing labels which are 25mm x 25mm which is 70.8661 point x 70.8661 point, yes they are different sizes but they need to be scaled to fit that size. I'm sure the issue is interpolationQuality as it works with a SwiftUI Image but don't know.

Comment: Just tried the same code but with UIGraphicsImageRenderer and it works perfectly, the result is sharp, the key is ctx.cgContext.interpolationQuality = .none don't know why it doesn't work with UIGraphicsPDFRenderer.

Comment: @user3533049 - it would help if you showed examples of the output. It would also be **very** helpful if you put together a [mre] so we can run your code directly, examine the results, and then (hopefully) provide a solution.